# Huawei Mobile Service Development - Storage Service Doesn't Exists

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, cloud-storage, huawei-mobile-services

I've been reading the huawei's documentation to implement their services. But I was unable to find a service to store mobile capture images on cloud storage. I found **DriveKit** by Huawei documentations but it doesn't fulfill my requirement. It's just like providing a service to access Google Drive cloud storage. Is there **similar service** provided by Huawei, like **Firebase Storage** to store files??

Comment: HUAWEI documentation [Cloud Storage](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-cloudstorage-introduction) You can also refer to this [article](https://dev.to/singlebubble1/want-a-simple-secure-and-efficient-file-storage-try-huawei-cloud-storage-kit-397j)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, HMS does not provide benchmarking function for Cloud Store in their AGC (AppGallery Connect)

However, in a developer event, it has been revealed beta access would be available by June.